# TableView with image background and blur effect - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, blur, uiblureffect

I have a little problem: I'd like to set an image to background in a TableViewController. I tried this:

```
class SquadreController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var sfondo = UIImage(named: "sfondo")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: sfondo!)

    }
```

Then I give the blur effect to the view, like this:

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
view.addSubview(blurView)
```

But there is a big problem. I'm working in a TableView and the TableView, TableCell, NavigationItem, etc. have all disappeared after I apply the blur. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about writing view.insertSubView(blurView, atIndex: 0)

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `view.insertSubView(blurView, atIndex: 0)` instead of `view.addSubview(blurView) as! UIImageView`

Comment: ahahahah you are a genius, or I'm a stupid XD 
thanks a lot guy, and Goodnight (I'm italian)!!!

Comment: In my case, `self.tableView.backgroundView!.addSubview(blurView)` did the trick instead of `view.insertSubView(blurView, atIndex: 0)`

Answer (score 2):

This question is an older question and Epic Defeater's response does in a way work, there is a much better way to accomplish this. Instead of adding `blurView`, you need to override the background view. Specifically you need to override `tableView.backgroundView`.

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
tableView.backgroundView = blurView
```

> This will only work if you have set the background color to clear.

Answer (score 0):

We can also add a subview below or above any other views using insertSubview

```
//Inserting below your subView
self.view.insertSubview(subview1_name, belowSubview: subview2_name)

//Inserting above your subView
self.view.insertSubview(subview1_name, aboveSubview: subview2_name)

/// You can use any of your view, instead of self.view
```